# how to sum column in datatables (i'm using codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using codeigniter and datatables for my view data. But i'm stuck how to get sum column. I have 2 fields named **barang_qty**, and **barang_qty_toko**. I need to sum this and display on datatables.

This is my Controller :

```
    function ajax_tableBarang(){
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }else{
        $this->load->library('datatables_ssp');
        $table = 'barang';
        $primaryKey = 'barang_id';

        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'barang_id', 'dt' => 'DT_RowID' ),               
            array( 'db' => 'barang_kode', 'dt' => 'barang_kode' ),
            array( 'db' => 'barang_type', 'dt' => 'barang_type' ),
            array( 'db' => 'barang_size', 'dt' => 'barang_size' ),
            array( 'db' => 'barang_qty', 'dt' => 'barang_qty'), //I want this field result from summation of barang_qty and barang_qty_toko
            array( 'db' => 'barang_harga', 'dt' => 'barang_harga' ),
            array( 'db' => 'barang_klasifikasi', 'dt' => 'barang_klasifikasi'),

        );

        $sql_details = array(
            'user'  => 'user',
            'pass'  => 'passwd',
            'db'    => 'pjtomato',
            'host'  => 'localhost'
        );

        $where = "";

        echo json_encode(Datatables_ssp::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where));
    }
}
```

And this is my view :

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-all">
<table id="tableAllItem" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Kode</th>
            <th>Jenis</th>
            <th>Ukuran</th>
            <th>Quantity</th> // Total of quantity (summation of barang_qty + barang_qty_toko) will display here
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Klasifikasi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And this is the javascript for datatables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function (oSettings){
    return{
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage": Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
        "iTotalPages": Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
    };
};

var t = $('#tableAllItem').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "<?php echo site_url('cAdminPage/ajax_tableBarang'); ?>",
    "columns": [
    { "data": "barang_kode" },
    { "data": "barang_kode" },
    { "data": "barang_type" },     
    { "data": "barang_size" },
    { "data": "barang_qty"},
    { "data": "barang_harga" },
    { "data": "barang_klasifikasi" },
    ],

    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    "rowCallback": function (row, data, iDisplayIndex){
        var info = this.fnPagingInfo();
        var page = info.iPage;
        var length = info.iLength;
        var index = page * length + (iDisplayIndex + 1);
        $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index);
    }
});
```

Please advice,
Thanks

Comment: can you tell me what you need to some?? ex `a=b+c`

Comment: it can be $summation = 'barang_qty' + 'barang_qty_toko'

Comment: get value of this `barang_qty` and this `barang_qty_toko` from database. and add them together

Comment: that's the question my brother :D I'm just learning PHP using CI and combine it with datatables.. Now i'm stuck how to get value of these variables, and how to sum these. because i'm still really newbie with ajax :D